# iOS file system directory data not persisting between builds, will it persist between App Store updates?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, ios16, data-persistence

I am saving a movie file in an iOS documents directory.  The file is saved fine and I can access and play it after it has been saved.  But when I rebuild the project I can't access the file, when I have checked the urls the application parent directory has changed.

Original saved url
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AB91D495-0AB4-4182-89D5-A124F748D474/Documents/BD1034BA-08BF-4F5D-813E-722C1FF9EC41/1F25B1B6-A05B-4178-8983-16C14AB8F263.mov

url from a file saved after the project has been built again
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/52EE7C76-88EA-42CC-965F-F9CD977825C0/Documents/C634D4E1-DB3C-4052-A7F5-0BFCF6EB3752/E68BDB15-6CB0-446B-893C-488839438588.mov

Will this happen between app store updates or will the OS handle it?  Surley if the user were to saved data inside this directory, If I do an app store update will the OS copy the data or not change the parent folder path?

The code I am using to save the movie files, for context this moves the files from the temporary directory to a newly created directory without any issues.

```
private func moveFileToNewDirectory(_ movieFileTempDirectory: URL) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let directoryUUID = UUID()
        
        do {
            /// Get the documents directory URL
            let documentsURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            
            /// Create a new directory URL inside the documents directory
            let directoryURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(directoryUUID.uuidString, isDirectory: true)
            
            /// Check to make sure its empty, we've just made it do it should be
            guard !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: directoryURL.path()) else { return nil }
            
            /// Create the new directory
            try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: directoryURL.path(), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            
            /// Create a new destination URL appended with the movieOutputFile filename
            let destinationURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(movieFileTempDirectory.lastPathComponent, isDirectory: false)
            
            /// Set the attributes - not sure if we need to do this yet
            //let attributes: [FileAttributeKey: Any] = [.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.complete]
            
            //try fileManager.setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: path)
            
           try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: movieFileTempDirectory.path(), toPath: destinationURL.path())
            
            return destinationURL
            
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you persisting the full URL? That's bad. Only persist the path relative to the Documents folder. Then you can rebuild the correct full path no matter what the Documents folder path is in the future.

Comment: Yes thank you, after posting, I spoke to a friend who also gave me the same information, upon testing this is the reason why it wasn't working.  I was saving the absolute path to the file in Core Data, whereas I should have been saving the relative path from the Documents folder, so Documents/xxx-xxx-xxx/movieFileName.mov then building a new URL using the file path to the documents folder 

Comment: Don't even save the `Documents` part of the path. Just save `xxx-xxx-xxx/movieFileName.mov`.

Comment: That's what I did in the end , Thanks again